# Group two tables so that they appear on successive pages

Tags: tables, floats, positioning, page-breaking

I have a table that is too big to fit on a page without shrinking the text to unreadable sizes. As a result, I have split it in to two. I can't use longtable to do this automatically as I am also using `\resizebox` to control the text size.

I'm finding that the tables are being placed so that table #1 is one page, two image floats are on the next page, then table #2 is on the third page. How can I force the two tables to be placed together on successive pages and not split apart by another float?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue a `\clearpage` before setting two tables. This should flush all pending floats before setting the tables, making them appear on successive pages.